# import numpy does load shared blas libraries to other modules

Tags: python, numpy, cython, blas

We have a library, linked as a module by Cython (core.so).
It uses BLAS, but it is compiled with -undefined,dynamic-lookup options in hope
that BLAS will be loaded in the runtime.

In the Enthought Python Distribution the following solution works perfectly:

```
import numpy #This apparently loads the shared BLAS library
import core
```

We tried it on a ''vanilla'' python distribution in Ubuntu 10.04 with numpy installed through apt-get (and liblapack-dev, libblas-dev installed in the same way).
It does not find the BLAS library. How can we make it work in the same fashion as in the EPD?

**UPDATE**:

This is done to get the same BLAS as in the numpy. For example, on Mac Os X box, EPD is compiled again MKL and is much faster than available BLAS (Accelerate Framework).

The output of `numpy.show_config()` is:

```
blas_info:
    libraries = ['blas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
    language = f77

lapack_info:
    libraries = ['lapack']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
    language = f77

atlas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['blas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
    language = f77
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1)]

atlas_blas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
    language = f77
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1)]

atlas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

Comment: Could you please add the output of `numpy.show_config()` on the Ubuntu box?

Comment: Linking *without* `-undefined,dynamic-lookup` should trivially solve the issue.  Why don't you go with that?

Comment: The value of `sys.getdlopenflags()` on both machines would be interesting as well.

Comment: @Sven Thank you! I have update my question with output of `numpy.show_config()` . `-undefined,dynamic-lookup' is needed to link against Numpy BLAS in the EPD, which is quite good, but this approach does not directly work without EPD.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, I cannot find any clues in the `show_config()` output -- BLAS config seems ok.  What about `sys.getdlopenflags()`?  By default, Python loads shared libraries in a private namespace.  You could try `sys.setdlopenflags(sys.getdlopenflags() | dl.RTLD_GLOBAL)` to change this.  (Note that this might lead to symbol conflicts.)

Comment: @Sven the output of `sys.getdlopenflags()` is `2` for both systems. However, `sys.setdlopenflags(sys.getdlopenflags() | dl.RTLD_GLOBAL)` does the job, however, I needed to put `import sys' and `import DLFCN as dl` before it

Comment: @Sven, the only question that remains is why EPD does load shared libraries in the global namespace.

Comment: Of course you have to import `sys` to use it, and simply `import dl` should work as well – or are you on Python 3?

Comment: Whether symbols are visible globally is architecture-dependent.  On some architectures, most notably Windows, smybols are *always* globally visible.

Comment: No, it is Python 2.6 installed through apt-get in Ubuntu 10.04 - and it does not find the `dl` module directly.